# Doorbell, intercom and door release

Tags: wiring, doorbell

[image]I have the same exact set up as the photo on [Decrease apartment intercom door buzzer volume](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/131032/decrease-apartment-intercom-door-buzzer-volume) and am trying to figure out how to disable the doorbell/buzzer without disconnecting door and intercom access. The brand name on the front panel is Jeron.  One tag inside the panel shows 3/92 the other 2015.  2015 has nothing to do with installation as I've been in the same unit since 2008.

Comment: please put all information into your question .... do not use links because the user could delete their question.

Comment: @MaryM It looks like you've created two accounts. Please see [this help page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) on how to merge them and thus regain control of your question

Comment: Does the bell/buzzer share the speaker with intercom? If so, you would have to find the way the circuit is setu and clip/cut the wire or trace for the bell/buzzer.

Comment: Yes they are shared.  The bell panel is located near the building lobby and connects to the speaker in the photo which is in the apartment.  Trying to find the wire in the intercom that is associated with the bell.  Not sure how to trace it.