# Interference or feedback on intercom

Tags: doorbell

Periodically, the speaker on my intercom system in my apartment emits a sound similar to a 1 kHz tone like [so](https://youtu.be/3FBijeNg_Gs)

The Intercom unit is a “Jeron” pictured here (front)

[image: jeron apartment]

And back [image: jeron intercom back]

It seems another savvy user reverse engineered the circuit here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/185619/134029

I’ve tried adding about 40 ohms of resistance on either side of the speaker to try and reduce the sound, but it did not help. I understand In adding any resistance to the circuit I would be permanently lowering the ring volume. I don’t care, I just want to stop hearing that noise.

I do not know what causes the noise, as its intermittent. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Appears to be a simple system with no digital components at the speaker.  Where is the control unit?  How many intercom units are wired together?  I would suspect either a feedback loop, problem with the controller, or an inductive interference problem.  If it's a master control system you don't have access to, you should talk to some of your neighbours to see if they have similar problems and make some recordings to document it, as you may have to push the building to fix the components on their end.

Comment: @KH thanks for your comment. There are 10 units in the building, so pretty small. I agree that it may ultimately be a building issue, but as you alluded to, it will be a long struggle to get it fixed if the problem truly lies somewhere in the control panel or the walls. I would prefer a local fix just to avoid all the drama. Any idea why adding the resistance on the speaker wires didn’t work? Maybe I just need more resistance? Unfortunately I don’t have a multimeter to really be able to see whats going on.